# What are the existing proofs for combinations?

Tags: permutations, combinations

There are times during which I have heard people refer to "**n** choose **k**" in a mathematical context, and I've learned that it has to do with combinations and can be expressed as $\displaystyle {n \choose k}$, or $_nC_k$, but what do these notations actually represent?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of "**n** choose **k**" falls under a category of mathematics known as combinations and permutations (one of the many concepts under the scope of probability), where a combination is a series of elements arranged irrespective of their order, and a permutation is a series of elements arranged according to an order. Before skipping straight to *n choose k*, we must first understand the basics.

Within the range of permutations, there are two types: repetition is allowed, or repetition is not allowed. When repetition is allowed, the formula is quite simply

$n^k$

where $n$ is the number of available elements to choose from and $k$ is the amount of times an element will be chosen. For example, say you are going to pick a combination for a 3-digit lock. For the first digit, you will have 10 possible digits (0 - 9), the next digit, and the digit after that, you will still have 10 possible digits to choose from. So you have 10 choices **and** 10 choices **and** 10 choices, and the rule of thumb in probability is that $and=multiply$, i.e $10\cdot10\cdot10=10^3=1000$ possible permutations.

Now what if repetition was not allowed? Then the first pick, you have $n$ choices and then you remove the element that has been picked from the pool (as you cannot repeat the pick), therefore the second pick you have $n-1$ choices, and luckily, there is an easy way of writing this:

$n!=n \times (n-1)\times (n-2) \times \ldots\times 2 \times 1$

So when repetition is not allowed, there are $n!$ permutations. However, what if we dont want to pick the whole set? What if we just want 3 from a set of 10, for example? Then the following needs to be done:

$\displaystyle \frac{10\times9\times8\times7\times6\times\ldots}{7\times6\times\ldots} = 10\times9\times8 = 720$

which can be written as $\displaystyle \frac{10!}{(10-3)!}$ or put more generally: $\displaystyle \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$, where $n$ is the number of elements from which can be chosen, and $r$ is the amount of elements you desire to choose. Be wary, however, since isn't the "**n** choose **k**" that is so often referred to just yet.

The next bit is combinations where the order of the elements does **not** matter, and this is the "**n** choose **k**" that is so often referred to. Look at the following arrangement; using 3 elements, how many combinations can be made, and how many permutations can be made:

Permutations: $123,132,213,231,312,321$, a total of $6$ permutations.

Combinations: $123$, a total of $1$ combination.

So, using the formula for the number of permutations, $\displaystyle \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$, we know that we simply need to **reduce** the permutations by the number of ways the same number of elements can be arranged differently, since combinations does not care for order, and of course, to figure out how many different orders $r$ elements can have, we simply calculate $r!$, so to calculate the number of combinations, the formula is now

$\displaystyle \frac{n!}{(n-r!)}\times\frac{1}{r!}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$

and that is the "**n** choose **k**" that is often mentioned, or in this case "**n** choose **r**", and so yes:

$\displaystyle {n \choose r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$

This, obviously, is not a purely mathematical proof and is not very rigorous at all, but it is the way I understand permutations and combinations and it has never exactly confused me.

Comment: Did you answer your own question?

Comment: I'm okay with this.

Comment: @5xum I did. For me it's a means of remembering things, the same way in which others remember things by writing them down on paper, I write a Q&A.